# Get access to subquerie's attributes

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a huge query with multiple includes and some subqueries. And I need to use `where` clause for attributes from main query and subquery simultaneously. Like this:

```
[Op.and]: [
  {
    '$type.id$': 1, //from main query
  },
  {
    '$creator.friends.id$': 2, //from subquery
  }
]
```

I have an error: `missing FROM-clause entry for table "creator->friends"` because it's only in subquery.
If I use `where` in `include`, I don't have access to `type.id` because it's in main query.
Filtering results after querying is also inappropriate, because I have limit+offset.

Comment: You can try to indicate `subQuery: false` option in main options of a query

Comment: @Anatoly yes, but I have duplicated rows because of m:m relations, so I have to use subqueries